# Form validation using regex is not working TextField MUI React

Tags: reactjs, regex, material-ui

I am trying to add a regex pattern in `inputProps` for validation of Textfield and `required` but both not working, on click of next the empty or wrong input is also getting entered.

```
  <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="s_firstName"
            label="First Name"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={user.s_firstName}
            onChange={handleChange} 
           
            inputProps={{pattern: "[a-z]"}
            required />
```

Please can you help what wrong is there validation not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258192/how-to-apply-a-pattern-to-a-textfield-to-only-allow-specific-characters
That can help you

Comment: @mchowdam; Thanks I tried but it didnt worked . I want to display message also about wrong entry. Any sample code if you can provide, MUI v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine, and `required` is working if you submit the form. It shows which field is required with a mark on the label.

In material ui,

> required  bool
> If true, the label is displayed as required and the input element is required.

You will notice a warning popup as you type in your input.

For validation, you could write your own function with `onChange`.

```
  const handleValidation = (e) => {
    const reg = new RegExp("[a-z]");
    setValid(reg.test(e.target.value));
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
```

With the `error` prop of `<Textfield>`, you could do something like this,

```
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="s_firstName"
            label="First Name"
            variant="outlined"
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => handleValidation(e)}
            error={!valid}
            required={true}
          />
```

Check out this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-joana-ctr9hu?file=/src/App.js) for code of two scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for responsing, what I have done how to display the error message and if user enters thewrong format and pressess next button its not working. @AnthonyDev220

Comment: for the one which I have asked there are many fields of form, then can be checked but how to show error message thant is coming on hover now.

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari could you rephrase your question? I don't quite get what you are asking.

Comment: I want to display error message also with the error. Secondly if user enters wrong value and presses submit button, the user moves ahead @AnthonyDev220:

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari I think you might need to post a new question with detailed example, and provide your code and what you have tried, to prevent excessive discussion here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805286/form-validation-mui-react-not-working-on-click-of-next-button  @AnthonyDev220:

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show error message then use "helperText"

```
<TextField
    error={value=== ""}
    helperText={value=== "" ? 'Please enter a value!' : ' '}
>
```