# ReactJS Material-UI: Accept only positive unsigned integer values in TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following input field, I would like it to accept only positive integers, without giving the possibility to insert the characters `- + , .`.

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  type="number"
  placeholder={'[1-100]'}
  id="simple-start-adornmhent"
  onChange={this.handleChangeField('amount')}
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 1 } }}
/>
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: If you use input with type="number" instead of TextField it should work. Do you need TextField?

Comment: I recommend looking at the [3rd party integration portion](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) of the documentation. You may also find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981996/how-can-i-set-material-ui-textfield-to-accept-only-hexidecimal-characters/53989369#53989369) helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Try This

```
  <TextField  type="number" 
     label="Short stop treshold"
     InputProps={{
        inputProps: { min: 0 }
      }}
     value={10}
     onChange={handleShortStopChange} />
```

Comment: Based on their documentation, I did this instead which prevented the css from getting messed up: `inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, min: 0, max: 999 }}`. Full element: `<Autocomplete freeSolo options={defaultNums} onChange={updateNewNum} renderInput={(params) => ( <TextField {...params} label="Amount" type="number" inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, min: 0, max: 999 }} onChange={updateNewNum} /> )} sx={{ width: '10em' }} />`

Comment: @takanuva15 how we can get the index of the selected row please to update the data array ?

Comment: @SidouMahmoud I'm confused what you mean by "selected row"? Are you referring to which option was picked in the Autocomplete? If so, you can access `e.target.dataset.optionIndex` in the onChange fn like so: `const onChangeFunc = (e: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string | number | null) => {
 console.log("selected row index is: ", e.target.dataset.optionIndex);
};`

Comment: I was refering to the row we are aiming to update, I found a solution with the `editable` parameter and `onRowUpdate` function, still try to make the same functionality with custom component (custom row). If you know how to define the same function `onRowUpdate`  on a custom component please tell me...

Comment: @SidouMahmoud Sorry I don't think I can be of any help there. It sounds like you are talking about an entirely different component.

Comment: yeah, I mean I want to fire `rowUpdate` event in a custom row (defined in a seperate component)

Comment: this does not let changing on its arrows to negative but you can still enter negative value manually. so it also needs the custom on change implementation

Answer (score 7):

In the onChange method you can create your own rule to deal with the data.

In this case below, if the input value is less then zero, then I set the value to zero.

This solved my problem. You can improve the rule as you need.

```
<TextField
    type={"number"}
    onChange={(event) =>
        event.target.value < 0
            ? (event.target.value = 0)
            : event.target.value
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work,

```
inputProps={{min:0}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

How about setting type to "text" and manually control the input?
try this:

```
<TextField
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={(e) => {
    let input = e.target.value ;
    if( !input || ( input[input.length-1].match('[0-9]') && input[0].match('[1-9]')) )
      this.setState({value:input})
  }}
  type="text"
  placeholder={'[1-100]'}
/>
```

with this code we only allow the first character to be [1-9] and the following charaters to be [0-9]. we also allow the TextField to be empty

Answer (score 4):

Finally following code worked for me, after combining few answers from other answers in this question.

This works for me with MUI in React Js.

```
<TextField
  type="number"
  InputProps={{
    inputProps: { min: 0 }
  }}
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event?.key === '-' || event?.key === '+') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone else came across it, this solution worked for me:

```
onKeyPress: event => {
  if(isNumberWithoutSigns && (event?.key === '-' || event?.key === '+')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: I got errors when I put the question mark in - so I'm not sure what's happening there.  However, this is a great solution!  If you want to disallow decimals, just add a check for '.' as well, and remember that many browsers allow 'e' as a number.  That starts getting to be a long conditional - I did this:  ['-','+','e','.'].includes(event.key)

Answer (score 1):

My way using HTML pattern.

- Allows only number.
- Shows number pad on mobile.
- Prevent pasting of
  non-numbers.
- Show error message if less than 1

[code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-glitter-7r693?file=/src/App.js)

add pattern props to inputProps to allow only 0 to 9.

```
pattern: "[0-9]*"
```

use e.target.validity.valid to check if pattern is valid (only allow 0-9)

```
 const [ value, setValue ] = useState(1)
    const onChange = (e) => {
          console.log('e.validity', e.target.validity.valid);
          if (e.target.validity.valid || e.target.value === '') setValue(e.target.value)
    }
```

add type="tel" (this will show number pad on mobile)

```
 <TextField
        variant="standard"
        name="price"
        value={value}
        fullWidth
        onChange={onChange}
        type="tel"
        error={value < 1}
        helperText={ value < 1 ? 'Min. 1' : '' }
        inputProps={{
            pattern: "[0-9]*",
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Might also try use "validator" props in TextField to restrict user to only input positive number.

```
<TextField
     validator: {(input) => {/*write your function here to check number input greater than 0*/}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt while setting the value in a state variable.

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  type="number"
  placeholder={'[1-100]'}
  id="simple-start-adornmhent"
  onChange={e=>setField(parseInt(e.target.value))}
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 1, max:100 } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Textfield in material ui using Hooks only maxlength 10 for mobile numbers NO text and Specialcaes**

```
     const [values1, setValues1] = useState("");
     const handleChange = (e) => {
        
        const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
       if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
          setValues1(e.target.value)
       }
    
      };       
    
    return(
     <TextField 
            label="Enter Mobile Number" name="mobile" 
            inputProps={{ maxLength: 10}} value={values1} type="text" 
            onChange={handleChange} className={classes.textfield} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  type="number"
  placeholder={'[1-100]'}
  id="simple-start-adornmhent"
  onChange={this.handleChangeField('amount')}
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { 
   min: 1,
   type: "text",
   pattern: "[0-9]*" 

} }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope what I'm proposing works for you or any other person that may still need it. I used a regex in the `onInput` prop, in conjunction with the `InputProps.inputProps.min` value. It works for me in [MUI v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/).

```
<TextField
    type="number"
    size="small"
    variant="standard"
    onInput={(e: any) => {
        const target = e.target;
        target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    }}
    InputProps={{
        inputProps: {
            min: 0,
        },
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

By using Regex you can remove non-numaric characters.
Check This snippet:

```
onChanged (text) {
    this.setState({
        YourAmountVariable: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
    });
}
```

this will remove any non numeric character from your input.

Comment: It doesn't work very well, it gives me several problems: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-sea-u0ey4